# Groups : $a$ and $b$ commute, prove $a^2$ commutes with $b^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a$ and $b$ are in $G$ and $ab=ba$ we say that $a$ and $b$ commute. Assuming that $a$ and $b$ commute prove the following:

> 1) $a^2$ commutes with $b^2$

Comment: You should at least show some of your work instead of just giving a question, and your question is definitely possible to work out by yourself.

Comment: i don't quite understand groups so i asked just to have an idea of how to approach this question sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might work on the following element as well:

$$a^2b^2a^{-2}b^{-2}=a(ab)b(b^2a^2)^{-1}=a(ba)b(ba)^{-2}=(ba)(ba)(ba)^{-2}=(ba)(ba)^{-1}=e_G$$

Comment: Well done, my friend! +1

Answer (score 13):

$$a^2b^2=aabb=abab=abba=baba=bbaa=b^2a^2$$

Comment: Thank you i didn't realize it was so simple..i tend to over think questions

Comment: My pleasure; we have some grouchy people here, don't be put off.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $ab=ba$
\begin{align*}
a(ab) &= a(ba) \\
(aa)b &= a(ba) \\
(aa)bb &= a(ba)b \\
a^2b^2 &= abab=bbaa=b^2a^2
\end{align*}