# Prove if in a group $a$ commutes with $b$, it also commutes with $b^k$ for any integer $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Prove if in a group $a$ commutes with $b$, it also commutes with $b^k$ for any integer $k$ (based on Gallian's *Algebra* text).

This site has [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465124/if-a-commutes-with-b-does-a-1-commute-with-b) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523112/groups-a-and-b-commute-prove-a2-commutes-with-b2) for individual integers; I'd like to prove it for *all* integers.  My proof is below.

1. Is my proof correct?
2. Can writing be improved?
3. Is my use of induction appropriate?
4. Is there a more direct proof than using induction?

---

**Proof:** Since $ab=ba$, $aba^{-1}=b$ and similarly $a^{-1}ba=b$.

We now show that for any integer $k$, $a^kba^{-k}=b$.  If $k>0$, we have $a^kba^{-k} = a^{k-1}(aba^{-1})a^{-(k-1)} = a^{k-1}ba^{-(k-1)}$.  By induction, we get $a^kba^{-k}=b$.  A similar induction can be used for $k<0$.  And for $k=0$, $a^kba^{-k}=b$ is trivial.

Consequently, $a^kb=ba^k$, QED.

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: You've proved that $b$ commutes with $a^k$. Apart from that (harmless) switch of $a$ and $b$, your proof is fine, except that it doesn't deal with the case of negative $k$ (which is quite easy using $a^{-k} = (a^{-1})^k$ and what you already have).

Comment: As a minor (whimsical aside): when I read *Gallian Algebra*, I wondered whether this was about some new field of algebra" that I had never heard of. If you'd written "Gallian's book *Algebra*" or just "Gallian *Algebra*", I wouldn't have been taken aback. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: @RobArthan I intended to cover negative $k$ in "similarly $a^{−1}ba=b$.... A similar induction can be used for $k<0$."  If that is not adequate, please explain why not.

Comment: Your "similarly ..." completion of the solution is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, it appears so.
2. I think it's perfectly fine, given what you are doing.
3. I think there's a much more general statement that's equally easy to prove: the collection of all elements that commute with $x$ forms a subgroup of a group.
4. This is 3. Suppose that $x$ and $y$ commute with $a$. Then $xy$ and $x^{-1}$ commute with $a$. To see this, we simply calculate:
   $$ axy=xay=xya,$$
   and for inverses we just multiply $ax=xa$ on left and right by $x^{-1}$ to obtain $x^{-1}a=ax^{-1}$.

Now that the collection of all elements that commute with $a$ is a subgroup, the result is obvious.

If you want to just prove your result, you can use the inverse trick to show that $a$ commutes with $b^{-1}$, and then you have proved the negative powers by proving the positive powers.

Comment: Your explanation hides the induction needed to prove that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $h \in H$, then $h^k \in H$ for any $k$.

Comment: @RobArthan I would hope that that fact, that groups are closed under taking powers of an element, is considered more basic than the question.

Comment: The question specifically asks whether there is a more direct method than using induction. Hiding the induction inside an assumed lemma is a less direct, although a much more structured approach. If people ask for a direct proof and you respond with a less direct but better structured proof, then good for you but you should explain what you have done.

Comment: @RobArthan If you consider the fact that powers of elements belong to a group to be a secret induction, and therefore all subsequent statements are induction-tainted, then I challenge you to provide even a definition of $a^k$ that does not use induction. Hence, it would be impossible to write down the question without using induction, hence there can be no induction-free proof. But that's silly. My proof does not use induction, beyond the statement that $a^k$ is an element of any subgroup containing $a$. That is part of the definition of being a group.

Comment: I am sorry. My concerns are more with the question than your answer. Our last two comments taken together will hopefully explain to the OP that there can be no "direct proof that does not use induction" but that a good proof (like yours) can be given that consigns the induction to a basic lemma that is required for any non-trivial reasoning about the notation $a^k$.

Comment: @RobArthan I believe a proof without induction can be done, but this requires a group to be defined in terms of the set of words in the generators together with evaluation maps on words that are associative. Whether that has buried induction still further into the definition of the group I leave to others to decide! But I can certainly see your point that if the OP asks for a proof that doesn't use induction, it's a good question as to whether that is explicit or implicit. As you say, the induction is tied into the concept of $a^k$ itself, and cannot be completely excised.